# Derivation of the Raychaudhuri equation following Wald - taking the trace

Tags: general-relativity, singularities

I am following the derivation of Raychaudhuri's equation as in Wald. There it is stated (Wald: General Relativity on page 218, equation 9.2.10), that from the relation
$v^c \nabla_c B_{ab} = -B^c_b B_{ac} + R_{cba}^d v^c v_d$
the Raychaudhuri's equations follow by taking the trace, the trace-free symmetric and the antisymmetric parts of this relation.
Now I don't really see how to proceed here.
Taking the trace on the left hand side gives $v^c \nabla_c \Theta$, since the expansion is just the trace of $B_{ab}$. But on the right hand side I don't know how to get the trace, nor the trace-free parts. Can someone help me with that?
The tensor field $B_{ab}$ can be decomposed into $\frac{1}{3} \Theta h_{ab} + \sigma_{ab} + \omega_{ab}$, where $h_{ab}$ is the spatial metric $g_{ab} + v_a v_b$ and $\sigma_{ab}$ and $\omega_{ab}$ are the shear and the rotation, respectively. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404773/2451

Comment: Nobody got some insights?

Comment: Have you tried taking the trace on both sides (i.e. Multiplying and contracting with $g^{ab}$), expanding both $g_{ab}$ and $B_{ab}$?

Comment: I have tried to multiply by h^{ab} which gives the proper time derivative of the Expansion on the left side, but I do not really manage to resolve the right hand side...

Comment: I will answer shortly

Comment: I would still be interested in the answer